# MySQL Select Statement Can't Get My Head Around it

Tags: mysql, sql

**Setup:**

(qty 1) Employee table (employeeID, employeeName)

(qty 1) PayType table (payTypeID, payTypeName)

(qty 1) PaySchedule table (payScheduleID, payScheduleName)

(qty 1) Junction table (Employee_has_PayType) where employees are assigned multiple Pay Types (employeeID, payTypeID)

(qty 1) Junction table (Employee_has_PaySchedule) where employees are assigned multiple pay schedules (employeeID, payScheduleID)

**What I need:**

I want to get all EmployeeIDs that are assigned one or all of these payTypeIDs (29,31,32) (from Employee_has_PayType) **AND** EmployeeIDs that have the payScheduleID 1 (from Employee_has_PaySchedule)

I want ONLY those EmployeeIDs that meet both of those criteria.

So far I have tried this:

```
SELECT 
    Employee_has_PayType.Employee_employeeID as 'type',
    Employee_has_PaySchedule.Employee_employeeID  as 'sched'
FROM
    Employee_has_PayType, Employee_has_PaySchedule 
WHERE 
    Employee_has_PayType.PayType_payTypeID in (29,31,32) 
AND 
    Employee_has_PaySchedule.PaySchedule_payScheduleID = 1
GROUP BY
    Employee_has_PayrollSchedule.Employee_EmployeeID
```

But it only returns all employeeIDs that have the paySchedule 1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to do a JOIN of the tables to get the results you want.

Comment: SELECT t.Employee_employeeID FROM
Employee_has_PayType t JOIN Employee_has_PaySchedule s ON t.Employee_employeeID = s.Employee_employeeID WHERE t.PayType_payTypeID in (29,31,32) AND s.PaySchedule_payScheduleID = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Employee_has_PayType.Employee_employeeID 
FROM Employee_has_PayType
JOIN Employee_has_PaySchedule 
  ON Employee_has_PayType.Employee_employeeID = 
     Employee_has_PaySchedule.Employee_employeeID
WHERE 
    Employee_has_PayType.PayType_payTypeID in (29,31,32) 
AND Employee_has_PaySchedule.PaySchedule_payScheduleID = 1
```

Comment: That was it. I was way off on the join. Thanks, Mark!